# Trying to merge a COUNT query in to an existing SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm stuck trying to merge a COUNT query in to an existing SELECT query that I have.

Currently, I use this SELECT statement to fetch some contact info:

```
SELECT contact.id_contact, contact.cname, contact.cemail, contact.trading_id, trading_name.trading_name
FROM contact
INNER JOIN trading_name ON contact.trading_id = trading_name.id_trading_name
WHERE (CHAR_LENGTH(contact.cname) > 0)
ORDER BY contact.cname
```

I also have this COUNT query which I need to somehow include in to the same SELECT statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(AlertID) AS CustomerAlertCountTotal FROM customer_support_dev.customer_alerts WHERE (AlertTradingID = @tradingid)
```

Basically I need to know how many 'AlertIDs' there are for each 'trading_name', and for that value to be returned in 'CustomerAlertCountTotal' - but by using just one query.

(If it makes a difference, I'm using a MySQL database)

Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Could you show us some sample input and output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT contact.id_contact, contact.cname, contact.cemail, 
contact.trading_id, trading_name.trading_name,CustomerAlertCountTotal
FROM contact
INNER JOIN trading_name 
ON contact.trading_id = trading_name.id_trading_name
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(AlertID) AS CustomerAlertCountTotal,AlertTradingID 
FROM customer_support_dev.customer_alerts )as count
on count.AlertTradingID=contact.trading_id
WHERE (CHAR_LENGTH(contact.cname) > 0)
ORDER BY contact.cname
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my hunch. If you're joining table with contact and costumer. You can merge something like this. Please let me know if there's a need of adjustment.

```
    SELECT contact.id_contact, contact.cname, contact.cemail, contact.trading_id, trading_name.trading_name, count(AlertID)
    FROM contact
    INNER JOIN trading_name 
     ON contact.trading_id = trading_name.id_trading_name
    LEFT JOIN customer_alerts
     ON contact.id = costumer_alerts.contact_id
    WHERE
     (CHAR_LENGTH(contact.cname) > 0) AND
     AlertTradingID = @tradingid
    GROUP BY contact.id
    ORDER BY contact.cname
```